# Report on accounts with no open activities in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am working on creation of report for "No open activities on Accounts of type Phone call" in advance find. I am able to get list of accounts with completed activities of type phone call but not accounts with no activities at all.

I tried assigning Activity type and subject to does not contain data, it still does not fetch accounts with no activities.

In below picture, you will see filters I have used,

[No Open Activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A5Mw.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should try using query like following:

```
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="primarycontactid" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="activityparty" from="partyid" to="accountid" alias="ae" link-type="outer">
      <link-entity name="activitypointer" from="activityid" to="activityid" alias="af" link-type="outer">
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="activitytypecode" operator="eq" value="4210" />
        </filter>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
    <filter type="and">
        <condition entityname="af" attribute="activityid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Code is based on following article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531006.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Left outer joins aren't supported in Advanced Find. You will have to use a custom query like the one Andrii posted.

EDIT: If you want to run your report with custom fetchXml maybe using the [Reporting Authoring extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45013) for SQL Server Data tools. You could copy & paste your fetchXml there and then upload the report into CRM.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the fetch xml through advance find, and modified query as needed. Now how do I put it back/ import the file into the system ?